# cakephp bake using command line in mac

Tags: macos, cakephp, command-line, mamp

i have setup the path variable in mac for cakephp to use command line baking. Everything works fine except the model gets created in a default location instead of a specific project which is just created.
that is when i write `cake bake` and select `M[model]`, the model gets created but in default folder i.e.

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cakephp/app/Model/
```

instead of

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testApp/Model/
```

i also tried it by changing the directory path(i.e the basic cd command)
where am i getting wrong? How do i solve it?

Comment: Did you use the -app parameter: cake -app /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testApp/app bake ?

Comment: Yes of course. Otherwise cake takes ../cakephp/app as your working path.

Comment: hey i used it and it asked for the database confifuration for testApp. I did so but how do i create model for my project?

Comment: and it also gave some warning-error before configuraing the db: Warning Error: scandir(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testApp/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ProjectTask.php, line 51].....n more

Comment: well i ran the same command again but before that i just ran cake -app /appslications/... and then the same with bake and now it worked.

Comment: thanks mate! can you please add your commnet as an answer to this question so that i can tick mark it as an answer

Comment: but now the files for views and everything get created but when i run my project in browser nothing is displayed. localhost:8888/testApp/ but nothing appears

Comment: Can you put the debug mode to 1 or 2 in Config/core.php ? Maybe you see whats wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a different cakephp core for your project you have to set the working app path when you use the cakephp console. This can be done with the -app parameter.

example:

```
cake -app /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testApp/app bake
```

Answer (score 1):

In a unix based environment i prefer using aliases relative to the project root opposed to mapping it to a specific cake lib globally.

Dump this in your respective shell config ".profile/.bashrc/.zshrc"

```
# Alias functions
alias cake='app/Console/cake'
alias cakelogs='tail -f app/tmp/logs/*'
```

and while your in you project root

```
cake {cmd}
```

should work as expected.